# How do I create select controls in Meteor

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

Is there a canonical way to populate a select control in Meteor and set the control to the existing value in the underlying data?
I have already found a way to populate the "options" in the select control. What I still need to do is created the options so that the correct option is selected to match the already existing data.

It seems most meteor examples imagine fairly simple forms. I have to deal with business data. I may have a record, which has child records... say contact emails.... so each line for a contact email has a select for "email type". Imagine there are 2 contact email records...when I display them i need to set the "selected" value for the correct option. but the only examples I find for this use session variables ??? to store the selected values... so they can be referenced inside the template that is laying out the select.

Use #with seems to have only one level... that is, I can't #with inside of an already existing #with

Answer (score 0):

The selected element needs to have this attribute:

```
selected="selected"
```

(or some variant - just selected works fine)

To conditionally include it, make a template helper (called isSelected for example) that return true/false based on your logic.  Your html loop for options will look like this:

```
<option value = "{{value}}" {{#if isSelected}} selected="selected" {{/if}}  >
    {{description}}</option>
```

As a refinement, rather than a helper, you could add a true/false field named isSelected to each record.  The template won't care whether it's a field or a helper.

For "Use #with seems to have only one level... that is, I can't #with inside of an already existing #with"

I have taken to fixing up the inner object with a reference to the outer, so both are accessible in the nested with.  For example, to associate any/all of one collection with a document, I prep the data:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper 'allSureties', (document) ->
  included = document.sureties or []  # the array that tracks ids for surety recs that this doc has
  _.map _sureties, (sure) ->
    sure.owner = document
    sure.isContained = sure._id in included
    sure.vents = "agent:sureties:#{document._id}:#{sure._id}"  # see you can get both IDs this way
    sure
```

and then my template uses that this way (notice you can access owner._id):

```
{{#each allSureties this}}
   {{switch value=value 
      fname=nickname 
      group="sureties" 
      on=nickname 
      off=nickname
      object=owner._id
      vents=vents
      _id=_id  }}
 {{/each}}
```

Hope this helps.